# check entity is attached by its identifier

Tags: java, jpa

Is it possible to check if entity with the specific identifier is attached to entity manager?

I know there is a method `EntityManager.contains`, but it accepts an entity and I have only entity's identifier.

Comment: May I ask, for what do you need that?

Comment: @AndreiI, there is a stored procedure which updates an entity. This procedure uses entity's identifier, so I wanted to check if such entity exists within current persistent context and if it does, I use `EntityManager.refresh` to update it from database

Comment: @AndreiI, `if the entity is managed, then call em.refresh()` how can I check having only an identifier?

Comment: OK, you said: "if the entity is managed, then you call em.refresh(). If not, then you do nothing". If you are afraid that you have some dirty entities that will be committed later, why not simply detaching all entities (em.clear()) ?

Comment: @AndreiI, no. Let me explain it more clearly. I do not have an entity in the first place. All I have is its identifier, I need a way to check if entity with this identifier is present in the current persistence context. And if it is present then I can safely call `em.refresh(em.find(...))`, but if it is not present, then this call is useless. My entity is immutable, so I do not care if it is dirty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way. If you use Hibernate, than you can do some tricks, e.g getting all managed entities and then searching for your ID manually. For other JPA implementations you could look for other tricks.